# Future negation with two statements using "won’t"

Tags: negation, contractions, future, conjunction-reduction, compound-predicates

I have a question about future negation using *won’t*. So, when I have a question that contains two parts connected by *and* and I want to make it known that those things both will not happen.

So for example:

> It **won’t** be counted as a typo and cause problems for your registration.

Would writing it that way negate the two parts of the sentence, making it read  like this:

> 1. It will not “be counted as a typo”.
> 2. It will not “cause problems
>      for your registration”.

Or I should instead use *won’t* twice? For example, like this:

> It **won’t** be counted as a typo and **won’t** cause problems for your registration.

Comment: The first variant is at best ambiguous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, if you were to read the first sentence for the first time, how would you interpret it?

Comment: For your question *“Or I should use two times something?”* you need to write that as “*Or should I use something twice?”* because English requires subject–auxiliary inversion in question, because we have a special adverb *twice* that we use instead of *two times*, and because we don’t want the adverbial to fall between the verb and its object here. You may wish to check out our sister-site for [ell.se], which may be better suited to your needs as a learner of the language that our site might be.

Comment: @tchrist, thanks for pointing it out, I will definitely check it out, but right now I need to understand whether this sentence will be interpreted in the way I intended :)

Comment: @tchrist, thank you! It was important for me to understand that a native speaker would get it right. _“It will not be counted as a typo that would end up causing problems with your registration.”_  - Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to say :)

Comment: I'd recognise the inherent ambiguity but the logical reading is the one tchrist gives. With some sentences, the causative reading may be less inferrable (and perhaps wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would interpret your example as reading:

> It will not be counted as a typo that would end up causing problems with your registration.

The implication is that a typo would trigger problems with your registration.

Structurally, this is a compound verb joined by a conjunction which is governed by a single subject: “It won’t X and Y”.  Expanded in full, it’s two separate sentences that start out the same:

1. **It won’t** be counted as a typo.

AND ALSO:

2. **It won’t** cause problems for your registration.

Since the subject is the same, we can use the conjunction *and* to make a compound verb with the same subject.

But there’s more in common than the initial subject alone; there’s also the *will not* part, so that bit can also be can be factored out under [conjunction reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_(linguistics)).

Conjunction reduction is perfectly normal, and usually reads better than not doing so, but you need to be careful that the remnants after reduction have enough parallelism that the reader will immediately understand to silently distribute the reduced part to both pieces.

Here your X and Y pieces are a bit unlike each other, so it may risk confusion. What I mean is that it’s a little odd because X is *be counted* while Y is *cause problems*.  This makes the reader re-parse to make sure they’ve got it right. They might also be unclear whether the negation part distributes: does the *not* part apply to both pieces or just to the first one?

Other conjunctions are possible:

- It will not be counted as a typo **or** cause problems for your registration.
- It will neither be counted as a typo **nor** cause problems for your registration.

It is certainly possible to use *won’t X and Y* to mean *won’t X and won’t Y*, but it’s also clearer to repeat the *won’t* part as you suggest. That way people don’t have to figure out how much reduction you’ve applied here.  One possibility is to skip applying any reduction at all and joins the two bits with a different word that better shows the implication you’re trying to make:

- It won’t be counted as a typo, **so** it won’t cause problems for your registration.

That’s a lot clearer.